# How to Build a definition and publish test results for a Java project with maven, Junit and selenium on Visual Studios Team Services VSTS

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium, junit, azure-pipelines

I have an automation script that uses maven POM.xml to import all the dependencies needed from selenium and junit. The main test uses selenium to open a browser, verify some information, close the browser and the test ends.

- When run as Junit it works fine:              [run as Junit test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgR9o.png)
- When run as Maven Test it works fine as well: [run as maven test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izwp5.png)

In both scenarios, the program opens the browser and navigates through the website as it should do for an automated test.

Now I need to integrate it to VSTS so I can visualize the overall pass/fail test on the VSTS dashboard but I'm not familiarized with this tool too much yet.

So far this is what I have managed to do:

- Deploy an agent on my WindowsPC (I want to execute and deploy the project on an Azure VM or another azure instance later on) NOTE: this is the same pc I'm successfully running the program using eclipse as shown in the screenshoots above. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts
- Create a build definition on VSTS but when I queue the definition the build fails: [build definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBdZl.png) and the [build fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqtKS.png).

I don't know why it can't find mt config.txt file since it is located on the same hosted agent in that same directory. I'll appreciate if someone is capable of guiding me through this process so I can run the program from the VSTS and visualize the overall tests that fail and pass on the VSTS dashboard.

**UPDATE:** I moved the config.txt file to the public directory and the build was successful(I still need to fix this issue because I do not want my work in a public folder).

Now the problem I have is that even though the build is successful and it looks like it is running my "3 tests", When I look at my pc, nothing is happening. it should open chrome and take a screenshot, then open Firefox and take another screenshot and finally open internet explorer and take another screenshot and save each test on different folders but it is only generating folders for chrome and internet explorer (but still those folders does not have the screenshot I'm asking, maybe because the browser is not being open on the computer.)

Here is the log: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S_MhAUmzj8i9phPQiqS06s0_1cCRrbF0

- [test output report generated on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKvkh.png)
- [test output on vsts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu5GU.png)

Comment: How do you use config.txt in the code? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share the sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share it on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know why it can't find mt config.txt file since it is located on the same hosted agent in that same directory.

It turns out that Java.IO. can't read files located on a shared network drive, I solved this by using the UNC path to that file (//"computername"/"directory"/"file.txt")

> Now the problem I have is that even though the build is successful and
>   it looks like it is running my "3 tests", When I look at my pc,
>   nothing is happening.

It took me a little reading to realize that to perform UI tests my agent needs to be set up in INTERACTIVE MODE. it can be done following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message. The error message tells you precisely what the problem is: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Y:\Automation Team\CopaQA\Architecture\local\config.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)`

You need to not rely on hard-coded paths.

You say you registered a build agent against your VSTS account... but did you change the agent queue for your build? If the agent queue is "Hosted", you're using Microsoft's hosted agent.

Comment: I did setup the build to run on the agent on my computer (it is set as defult) I'm not using the microsoft hosted agent. For the same reason, I don't know why it can't find my config.txt since it is located in that directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you put the agent into the "default" queue. If you didn't change your build definition to use the "default" queue, it's using the Hosted one. If you're referencing a file on your machine, you're sure the file exists on your machine, and the build is telling you the file isn't found, then the only reasonable conclusion is that the build *isn't running on your machine*.

Comment: my built definition is using my default agent. I did make sure of that when creating the build definition on the agent queue section.

Comment: check out my update where I show you the  default agent set up on the build definition,the  agent online and the agent running on my computer

Comment: Moving the file to my desktop I get the following: Results :
Tests in error: 
  initializationError(flujoX.X_Test): C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\AutomationTeam\CopaQA\Architecture\local\config.txt (Access is denied)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0